Stehen Partikeln immer vorne in der rechten Satzklammer?
In einem Artikel zum topologischen Feldermodell habe ich folgendes gelesen: "Partikeln stehen immer vorne in der Rechten Satzklammer (RSK), und zwar entweder alleine oder angeschrieben."
Wenn diese einfache Formulierung tatsächlich stimmt, so ist es wohl besonders für Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache-Lernende der Mühe wert, sich mit den Grundzügen des topologischen Feldermodells zu befassen.

Du meinst mit RSK sicher den Amateurfunkverband von Kenia, und mit TFM das Thüringer Finanzministerium, oder?

@Georg: mnch. fördert es d. Lesbkt., wen. Abk. zu ben.

Aus der Frage wird nicht eindeutig klar, was genau mit Partikeln gemeint ist.

Naja, Partikeln in der Satzklammer können nur Verbalpartikeln sein. Das ist jetzt arg pingelig.

Nochmal die Frage: Was ist die Quelle für die zitierte Aussage? (Wäre interessant was das für ein Artikel ist).

Das ist nicht richtig.
Die "rechte Satzklammer" ist das zusammengesetzte Prädikat, soweit die Prädikatsbestandteile eben hinten im Satz stehen. Das zusammengesetzte Prädikat kann aus mehreren Verben bestehen ("weil er das hätte wissen müssen") oder aus Verben zusammen mit anderen Elementen.
Die Partikel gehört als ein Bestandteil zu einem Partikelverb, allerdings ein lockerer Bestandteil. Die Partikel steht im Deutschen vor dem verbalen Grundwort: "ab+schätzen, ein+sehen, auf+geben" usw. Das ist erwähnenswert, weil es im Englischen umgekehrt ist: "to give up" (direkt vergleichbar zu "auf geben"). Das bezieht sich aber auf das einzelne Partikelverb, nicht auf das zusammengesetzte Prädikat, das dann die rechte Satzklammer bildet. Die Partikel steht nicht vor dem zusammengesetzten Prädikat, also nicht unbedingt am Anfang der rechten Satzklammer:

"dass er das hätte abschätzen können müssen" (zusammengesetztes Prädikat kursiv, Partikel fett).

Die von dir genannte Quelle verwechselt also "Prädikat" und "Verb", leider etwas sehr häufiges (könntest du die Quelle angeben?).
Ein paar Feinheiten noch dazu:

Man kann die obigen Beispiele mit der Umordnung, durch die das finite Verb (z.B. oben "hätte") am Anfang der RSK erscheint, als Oberfeld besonders benennen. Dieses Oberfeld zählt aber als ein Teil der RSK (siehe zB A. Wöllstein in: Ossner & Zinsmeister (Hrsg.):
Sprachwissenschaft für das Lehramt. Paderborn: Schöningh, 2014, S.181-210. Siehe S.203).
Es ist natürlich sehr häufig, dass das Partikelverb das hauptsächliche Inhaltswort des Prädikats ist, und daher am Anfang des Prädikats steht (und somit dessen Partikel ganz am Anfang). Es gibt aber eindeutige Fälle mit Partikelverben, die nicht das hauptsächliche Inhaltswort eines Satzes sind (sondern eines selber einbetten), z.B. "zu essen anfangen"

Es gibt übrigens einige sehr kuriose Fälle, aus deutschen Dialekten, in denen es ausnahmsweise doch anders ist - aber dass es kurios wirkt, zeigt, dass es eben nicht die Regel ist. Das folgende findet sich im Wikipedia-Artikel "Partikelverb", siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb#Trennung_im_Satz – hier in hochdeutscher Übersetzung:

"Haben sie gerade an zu essen gefangen?"


Im Hauptsatz aber stimmt diese Regel ziemlich genau, oder ... ?

Etwas öfter, weil die vorgezogenen finiten Verben im Oberfeld wegfallen - aber auch im Hauptsatz ist es nicht grundsätzlich anders. Siehe die Hauptsatz-Variante zum obigen Beispiel mit "anfangen": "Er hat schon [zu essen angefangen]". Sogar die Oberfeld-Bildung ist noch möglich, denn es gibt sie manchmal auch mit infiniten Verben. Obwohl das dann sehr anspruchsvolle Sätze sind, ist es grammatisch klar möglich: "Sie würde es [haben zugeben müssen]".

Fehlerhaft ist die Formulierung außerdem, weil sie Sätze vorhersagt wie "Packen hat er es nicht ein _  wollen". Hier muss die Partikel ins Vorfeld mitgenommen werden ("Einpacken hat er es nicht wollen"). Der Fehler ist, Partikel und Satzklammer direkt aufeinander zu beziehen, obwohl die Partikel nur auf ein einzelnes Verb direkt bezogen ist.
